# Hinge2Joint - Implementations do not seem to Support ::GetAngleImpl()

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

In `gazebo/physics/ode/ODEHinge2Joint.cpp`, `ODEHinge2Joint::GetAngleImpl(...)`, the function does not attempt to return the angle for the first joint axis (though debugging the code and examining the values indicates that there is a value there), and does not support multiple axes. `BulletHinge2Joint:GetAngleImpl(...)` says it is not implemented. Changeset: `e93d70fe8d38+ (gazebo_1.3) gazebo_1.3.1`

What is the plan regarding these types of joints? If we want co-located joints, is there some workaround to make this happen?
We tried using 'null bodies' (zero mass, zero inertia) in URDF a couple of weeks ago, but that did not work. We also have seen gerkey's [issue](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/307/00-mass-causes-exception) about zero mass in SDF raising an exception.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/532/hinge2joint---implementations-do-not-seem-to-support-::getangleimpl()/) by [eacousineau](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/120/eacousineau/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 27 on 2012-12-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) on 2013-01-11**:
General co-located joints (other than hinge2) will require creation of your own joint types in ODE for now.  The way things are setup in right now the ODE solver, zero inertia link elements will have infinite velocity with application of any finite wrench.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I've ticketed the [issue](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/380/fix-hinge2joint-getangleimpl).

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2013-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0